# Powershell devbox Magento installation using Docker

Tags: powershell, magento, docker, local

Today I am trying to install the [Magento DevBox now](https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/configure/). Here you can configure your choice, so I choosed for the **Create New Installation**

I have downloaded the zip file and extracted it in the location:  .docker

Now when I use PowerShell to locate to this folder and I want to install this package it asks me about a sudo password for Magento 2. I did not created this password before so how am I supposed to solve this? Because after blank imputs for this password for instance it stops the installation..

In the picture a printscreen:

[image: please look at this printscreen of the PowerShell screen]

So this is what u get after 3 attempts to get through this...

```
Install Magento 
.[sudo] password for magento2: 
Sorry, try again
. [sudo] password for magento2: 
Sorry, try again
. [sudo] password for magento2: 
Sorry, try again
. sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts Executing shell command: 
cd /var/www/magento2 && COMPOSER_AUTH="{\"http-basic\": {\"repo.magento.com\ repo.magento.com magento/project-community-edition:2.1.6 .
```

Comment: ^ If that comment is important information, please delete it and then add it to the question proper, by editing the question. You will also need to explain what it is. Thanks.

Comment: Hello I have edit my question now thank you

Answer (score 1):

No answer, I guess it is an empty password, but sudo is not accepting it. What I did to solve the problem was, first connect to the docker container using the SSH port ( user magento2 ), and changed the password to "magento2".
After that, I executed m2devbox-init.bat again, used that password and it worked!

Hope it helps.